# Вставить три звезды в строке после первой цифры

Tags: pascal, строки

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в коде. В общем надо вставить три звезды в строке после первой цифры. Но вставляет сразу после первого символа.

```
var s:string;
i:integer;
begin
readln(s);
i:=1;
while (i<=length(s)) and (s[i]<'0') and (s[i]>'9') do
    inc(i);
insert('***',s,i+1);
writeln(s);
end.
```

Comment: опять эти and'ы... у вас в условии для while "женская логика". условие всегда ложно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще тут простая ошибка с условием цикла:

```
var s:string;
i:integer;
begin
readln(s);
i:=1;
while (i<=length(s)) and ((s[i]<'0') or (s[i]>'9')) do
    inc(i);
insert('***',s,i+1);
writeln(s);
end.
```

s[i] не может одновременно быть s[i]<'0'  И s[i]>'9'

Answer (score 0):

Вы должны сравнить число с числом.. А не char со string
К сожалению, нету ничего из паскаля, чтобы помочь кодом

Comment: однохренственно что сравнивать 0..9 или '0'..'9'

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно заменить строку с условием на

```
while (i<=length(s)) and (ord(s[i])>48) and (ord(s[i])<58) do
```

48 это значение символа 0 , а 58 соответственно символа 9

Comment: получилось после первой НЕ цифры.

Comment: Главное дать направление решения, а не решать за человека.
думаю он понял какой функцией можно обойтись :)

можно использовать и конструкцию **IN ['0'..'9']**

Comment: прекрасно работает условие s[i]<'0' or s[i]>'9'. Тут проблема не в функциях, а в условии. да.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал так:

```
  Var
  Str: String;
  i, Len, Position: Byte;

begin
  Write('Vvedi stroku: ');
  ReadLn(Str);

  i:=1;
  Position:=0; // пусть пока неизвестно есть ли цифры
  Len:=Length(Str);
  While (i <= Len) Do // можно было бы использовать и цикл for
    Begin
      If (Ord(Str[i]) In [48..57]) Then // Условие для Windows
      If (Ord(Str[i]) In [30..39]) Then // Для Паскаля условие должно выглядеть так!
        Begin
          Position:=i+1;
          Break;
        End;

      i:=i+1;
    End;

  WriteLn;
  If (Position > 0) Then // если цифры есть то:
    Begin
      Insert('***', Str, Position);
      WriteLn('Stroka = ', Str);
    End
  Else // иначе - выводим сообщение
    WriteLn('V stroke net czifr!');

  WriteLn;
  WriteLn('Davi na ENTER!');
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю что есть 1 проблема. Как '0' сравнивать как число.
Смотрите:
'1', '0' ,'34234' - тип String.
1, 2, 6, 4567 - тип Integer(или Byte, Longint)
Используйте процедури Val() и Str().